# Error when doing a test callout to a REST web service

Tags: apex, callout

I'm trying to test a http callout from the developer console but I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when I try to do a POST.  Only working with the sample callout code mentioned here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
    String content = '{"Customer": "500269677900", "Name":"TestCallout"}';
    String endp = 'http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk';
    //Set HTTPRequest Method
    req.setMethod('POST');

   //Set HTTPRequest header properties
   req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
   req.SetEndpoint('http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk');
   req.setMethod('POST');


   //Set the HTTPRequest body   
   req.setBody(content);    

   Http http = new Http();

 try {

    //Execute web service call here     
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  

    //Helpful debug messages
    System.debug(res.toString());
    System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
    System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());

 } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
System.debug('*****'+e.getMessage());
 }
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error with the above, since the server expects json I thought it would set encode the response appropiately.  If I insert {} into the request body I get a 502 Bad Gateway.  The same test call with the same body works fine in a rest resting tool like the Advanced REST Client.

the following works fine on the command line and returns a JSON response:

```
  curl http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk --data '{"NumerVidskiptamanns": "500269677900", "Heiti":"Test"}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Any pointers or ideas for me?

edit:  posted updated code

Comment: have you verified that is the correct endpoint?

Comment: i'm not fluent in REST + SF, but another idea is to check that you are setting the REST header correctly

Comment: Problem with REST service, not SFDC consumer.

Comment: The endpoint is correct, I've called it successfully via Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off compression, this worked fine for me from from anonymous apex.

```
String content = '{"NumerVidskiptamanns": "500269677900", "Heiti":"Test"}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();
req.SetEndpoint('http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk');
req.SetBody(content);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.toString());
```

The debug log shows

```
10:41:35:829 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the REST service, not the Salesforce consumer.

When the JSON is valid, he closes the connection instead of sending you any response.

1. CURL request:

   ```
   $ curl http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk \
   > --data '{"Customer": "500269677900", "Name": "TestCallout"}' \
   > --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
   curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
   ```
2. Chrome request:

   [image: Socket closed]

Comment: Just wrong parameters, my bad.  This here payload works: 

      {"NumerVidskiptamanns": "500269677900", "Heiti":"Test"}

Comment: I've gotten further with this, I'm wondering now how to use the JSONGenerator class to generate the JSON string, since the field names in the service don't respond 1-to-1 to SF field names.  Will I have generate it as a string and then use a method to JSONify the payload, since I'm fairly sure that the 400 BAD REQUEST is because I'm sending junk data via my callout that the service endpoint can't parse.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work when I execute the Anonymous Apex call:

```
       String content = '{"NumerVidskiptamanns": "500269677900", "Heiti":"Test"}';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

     /* JSONGenerator js = JSON.createGenerator(true);
     js.writeStartObject();
     js.writeStringField('NumerVidskiptamanns','500269677900');
     js.writeStringField('Heiti','Test');
     js.writeEndObject();
     */

    req.SetEndpoint('http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk');
    req.SetBody(content);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    system.debug('++++*****++++'+req.GetBody());
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setCompressed(true);

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('++++*****++++'+req.GetBody());
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }

     System.debug(res.toString());
```

Seems that it was sufficient to set the correct header there.  At least I get no errors in the debug log.

Comment: nope, still having problems with this.  Anyone with any ideas?  The answer from the server is always 502 Bad Gateway, but always works when I just use curl on the command line or use a tool like the Advanced REST Client.

Like for example, the following works for me :

 curl         http://212.30.237.35:8080/VerkbokhaldRestService.svc/StofnaVerk --data '{"NumerVidskiptamanns": "500269677900", "Heiti":"Test"}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'